# Split an array of numbers to arrays whose sum is less or equal than a given number

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, algorithm

If array is: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
and max-sum is 25
The script should create three arrays
arr1:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] (sum=21)
arr2:[7,8,9] (sum=24)
arr3:[9,10] (sum=19)
I can create the first array but not the others, someone could kindly help me?

My jquery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
  total = 0;
  newOne =[];
  for(i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
       if(total<= (25-numbers[i])){
        total += numbers[i];
        newOne.push(numbers[i]);
       };
    };
  numbers.splice(0,newOne.length);
  console.log(newOne);  
  console.log(numbers);     
});
```

Thanks to all

Comment: Can splited array have only one element?

Comment: How about the given number is a small number, for instance, 5, how to split the rest of the array?

Comment: What are the constraints on the problem? Is the original array always the numbers from one up to some limit? Is it always necessary to get three subsets? (Apparently the subsets need not be disjoint; is that right?) When asking about number theory problems, it will save a lot of time if the problem is also stated in mathematical terms.

Comment: You could move the first item in the `numbers` array to the end and then loop through it again, repeating this process until you've done it for every item in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    total = 0;
    coll = [];
    newOne = null;
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (newOne !== null && total + numbers[i] <= 25) {
            total += numbers[i];
            newOne.push(numbers[i]);
        } else {
            // We enter in the else for i = 0 and when we have to
            // create a new subarray
            if (newOne !== null)
            {
                console.log(newOne);
            }

            total = numbers[i];
            newOne = [ numbers[i] ];
            coll.push(newOne);
        }
    }

    // We have to print the last subarray (because normally
    // a subarray is printed only when it's filled)
    console.log(newOne);     
}
```

I don't splice the original array. I even put in `coll` all the various sub-arrays.

If you only want to print the array at the end:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
total = 0;
coll = [];
newOne = null;
for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (newOne !== null && total + numbers[i] <= 25) {
        total += numbers[i];
        newOne.push(numbers[i]);
    } else {
        total = numbers[i];
        newOne = [ numbers[i] ];
        coll.push(newOne);
    }
}

// Here we print the subarrays
for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++)
{
    console.log(coll[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a little simpler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
  var total;
  var newOne = [];
  var index = -1;
  while (numbers.length) {
    total = 0;
    index++;
    newOne[index] = []
    while (total + numbers[0] <= 25 ) {
      total += numbers[0];
      newOne[index].push(numbers.shift());
    }
  }  
  console.log(newOne);  
  console.log(numbers);     
});
```